# Sublime Text: How do I rename the Directory in which I'm editing?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I opened my folder called 'Tsunami++' in sublime text and I want to be able to rename it without having to close sublime text, open file explorer, find the folder, rename it, and open sublime again.

When I right-click the folder and select the rename option, type a new name, and hit enter, I get a quick 5 second message at the bottom that says

```
Unable to rename: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\ramal\\Desktop\\Tsunami++' -> 'C:\\Users\\ramal\\Desktop\\Tsunami-plus-plus'
```

It says access is denied, shows the path to the directory, and what the path would be with the new name

I checked if the name was valid, and it was.
I checked if there was already a folder in my Desktop folder called Tsunami-plus-plus, and there wasn't, so it's not a matter of name validity or name collisions

My end goal is to be able to change the name of my current working directory within Sublime Text. How do I do this? What do I do to fix this error?

Comment: You need to close all the open files you have in that directory first, but you may still need to close out of Sublime before you can rename it.

Answer (score 0):

1. close Sublime Text
2. edit `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Local/Session.sublime_session` by changing dir to dir2 (making sure you avoid errors there; do this at your own risk)
3. rename dir to dir2
4. re-open Sublime Text